# IllegalArgumentException: Unmanaged descriptor

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, illegalargumentexception

i am trying to run a geoquery everytime someone select a place from PlaceAutoComplete fragment and show the markers on the map. It is working fine for the first.When i start the app the icons are are all fine the geoquery is running fine, but when i enter a location second time the app crashes showing an error   **llegalArgumentException: Unmanaged descriptor** below is what i am trying to do.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = 
 (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)

 getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById
 (R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new 
  PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.

   Toast.makeText(getContext(),place.getAddress(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());

            Double latitude1 = place.getLatLng().latitude;
            Double longitude1 =place.getLatLng().longitude;
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude1,longitude1);

            getPeople(latLng); // method to call geofire query
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
    return mMainView;
}


public void getPeople(LatLng latLng1){
mMap.clear();
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(latLng1)
        .radius(2000)
        .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
        .fillColor(0x220000FF)
        .strokeWidth(1)
 );
 DatabaseReference ref = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Location");
 GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
 GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new 
 GeoLocation(latLng1.latitude, latLng1.longitude), 2);
 geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(final String key, GeoLocation location) {
  UIDLocation.put(key,location);
 marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource
 (R.drawable.ic_mapmarker2));
        markers.put(key, marker);
 for (Map.Entry<String,GeoLocation> entry : UIDLocation.entrySet())
        {
        final Marker marker = markers.get(entry.getKey());
        if (marker != null) {
        DatabaseReference mUser = 
              FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("People")
              .child(string);
                    mUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
  {
                            String display_name = 
                         dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String status = 
                         dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                            String image = 
                          dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                            PeopleInfo info = new PeopleInfo();
                            info.setName(display_name);
                            info.setStatus(status);
                            info.setImage(image);
                            marker.setTag(info);
     String iconName = dataSnapshot.child("iconName")
                      .getValue().toString();
   Context context = getContext();
   int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", 
   context.getPackageName());
   String s = String.valueOf(id);

   Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),id);
   marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id));
   }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError 
                   databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                         }
                     }

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mFusedLocationClient =
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());

            Task task= mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new 
            OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {              
                    if (location != null) {
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        markeroptn = new MarkerOptions();
                        markeroptn.position(myPosition);
                        markeroptn.title("You are Here");
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));           
   mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition,10));
                        getWorkMen(myPosition);



                    }
                }
            });
```

So far what i have learned from the posts on SO that its because the program is trying to set the icon on marker which is already there. I tried clear() map in the begining of getPeople() but still it is showing the same error.It works fine first time.  i also tried remove() also but its also not working.

Comment: Which version of `play-service-map` you are using?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

Comment: I met this problem long time ago when using version 10, then adding some more feature and update to ver 11 and now the exception never thrown again. But it seems not to come from the lib version. Something  I remember I did to my logic are: Always keep the reference of any marker or other map elements. After remove it, set to null immediately. Changing marker icon requires not too big bitmap... That's I can remember for now

Comment: i used map.clear() first and then called setIcon method later in the code, is map.clear() not enough to remove the markers and how do you set a marker to null? I think the problem is that method is calling setIcon on a position where already there was a marker and somehow it is still there that's why it's not setting an icon again.

Comment: I don&#39;t use `map.clear` because to me it&#39;s quite dangerous. I need to keep  the `Marker` reference so I can change its icon, position... If I call map.clear, it means all of my `Marker` reference is invalid. I manually call `marker.remove` then set marker to null myself to clear it from the map, this way i know if the marker is already cleared by checking for null and may avoid unwanted error trying to access a removed marker.

Comment: can you please post some code how do you set the marker to null.  I have also tried marker.remove() to remove them manually and still, the error was occurring.

Comment: This line in your code inside `onKeyEntered`: `UIDLocation.put(key,location);
 marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource
 (R.drawable.ic_mapmarker2));`. Where is the `marker` variable come from, is it an instance variable that you create somewhere else?

Comment: @TamHuynh marker is defined outside the method, its a global variable.    can you also please look at this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592252/view-setparams-not-working-properly-in-firebase-recycler-view

Answer (score 3):

The problem may come from the way you manage the `Marker` variables. In the code, you store a `marker` variable as global outside of the method scope. When calling `map.clear()`, it makes the `marker` variable invalid and if somehow you still use this variable to set something, it may cause the exception. The same thing happens with the `markers` Map you use to map `key` and `Marker`, it's not being cleared when `map.clear()`.

Try to manage your map elements more carefully, clear each map element dependently and avoid using `map.clear()`.

**Suggestion approach:**

Create new marker

```
private void addMarker(String key, LatLng latLng) {
    // Clear the current marker before add the new one
    if (marker != null) {
        marker.remove();
        marker = null;
    }

    // Store new marker to the variable
    marker = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(latLng)
        .radius(2000)
        .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
        .fillColor(0x220000FF)
        .strokeWidth(1)
    );

    // Add to markers map if needed
    markers.put(key, marker);
}
```

Clear all markers (clear manually every marker variable available, don't use `map.clear`:

```
public synchronized void clear() {
    // markers is the marker map
    for (Marker marker : markers.values()) {
        try {
            marker.remove();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Clear all the marker map
    markers.clear();

    // Marker is the your global marker variable
    marker.remove();
}
```